# How to make configure the src/main/java without affecting the other src folder

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am trying to add a package inside src/main/java project, but it also implements same changes to the other src folder, which I don't want.

I am trying to do something similar to this blog http://briansjavablog.blogspot.com/2013/01/spring-web-services-tutorial.html

[image: screenshot from eclipse]

Comment: Those two folders are the same on disk. Eclipse just shows it in a Java package manner and in a folder structure manner. But it's the same. And it's normal.

Comment: They are the same folder; Eclipse is just show you two representations of it.  One as package space, the other as physical space.  The physical space might contain other files that wouldn't be seen in the package space.

Comment: I am trying to do something like this blog.
http://briansjavablog.blogspot.com/2013/01/spring-web-services-tutorial.html

Comment: Refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18790106/1743880 It's just a difference in Eclipse config.