# HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet in eclipse maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, servlets

I am trying to run a simple servlet in maven using eclipse. But getting error 500.  Please see what I am doing wrong.  Main concern is how to run a servlet in maven as I am not familiar with maven .

index.jsp

```
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>Hello World!</h2>
  <form action="mylog" method="post">  
  loginID:<input type="text" name="name"/><br/>
  <input type="submit" value="login"/> 

  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

mylog.java (servlet class)

```
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.io.PrintWriter;

  import javax.servlet.ServletException;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


   public class mylog extends HttpServlet {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


   public mylog() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


     protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
     }


     protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      String n = request.getParameter("name");

      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
      out.print(n);
      out.close();

      doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

web.xml and directory structure- see attached image
[image]

error stack

```
     HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class com.issac.mylog

  type Exception report

  message Error instantiating servlet class com.issac.mylog

 description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

 exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class     com.issac.mylog
  org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
  org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
  org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
  org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
  org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1100)
  org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:687)
  org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
  org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
  org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
  java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

root cause

 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.issac.mylog
  org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
  org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
  org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
  org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
  org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
  org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
  org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1100)
  org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:687)
  org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
  org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
  java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a source folder `src/main/java` and move the java source file there

Comment: tried creating it but shows "this folder is already a source folder" , also when I go to build path->order and export, it shows all three src/main( resources, java & test) but with "missing" written in bracket for src/main/java& src/main/test. Also I was trying a similar project two days ago there it showed all three, and servlet was workin too.

Comment: Sounds like Eclipse is out of sync with the file system. Try deleting the project in Package Explorer (view only - not files), then re-import as a Maven project

Comment: yes, there was some issue with eclipse that it didn't show all three folders. But now that I've tried two diff projects it works fine for one but same problem for other project. Isn't there a permanent solution for this.

Comment: There can be a number of different causes. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18790106/eclipsemaven-src-main-java-not-visible-in-src-folder-in-package-explorer). One surefire way to ensure everything shows up is to create the project using a Maven archetype and import

Comment: the error 500 persists for a different project with similar servlet  even after placing under specified folder.

Answer (score 2):

`src/main/resources` is for placing `properties` files (or static resources), So the server could NOT find class files, so you need to create the Java source files under `src/main/java` folder.

Also, make sure that the `.class` files are generated and available in the Server classpath (i.e., under `WEB-INF/classes`), which will resolve the  above `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`