# src/main/java path is not showing in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot

I am Unable to see src/main/java in eclipse but whenever I run the class it shows the error I have also checked the build path there is no file missing.

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Maybe a duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18790106/eclipsemaven-src-main-java-not-visible-in-src-folder-in-package-explorer

Comment: Earlier I followed this one but didn't get the solution. Now I just deleted the dependency that I added recently and my src/main/java just showed up

Comment: Maybe answering your own question would be a good way for others suffering from the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

**It is resolved** I have deleted recent added dependency "netflix-hystrix" one and after force updating the maven my src/main/java got restored I didn't how but it works in my case